# How do I evaluate this:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n²}(e^x −1 −\frac{x}{1!} −\frac{x²}{2!}−\cdots\frac{x^n}{n!})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponentiation

How do i evaluate this sum :$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n²}(e^x −1 −\frac{x}{1!} −\frac{x²}{2!}−\cdots\frac{x^n}{n!})$$

Note: I 'd surprised if it is convergent

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Using Maclaurin Expansion: $$-e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}( −1 −\frac{x}{1!} −\frac{x²}{2!}−\cdots\frac{x^n}{n!})$$

Answer (score 2):

The expression in parentheses converges to $0$ because $e^x=\sum\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Together with the fact that $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ converges absolutely, we conclude that your series converges as well.

Comment: this answer was my first attempt !!!!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik If that was your first attempt how come you'd be surprised if it is convergent?

Comment: sorry i posted the question with wrong way, and i mean n²(...) not 1/n² , now since it's answred i can't edit the question

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Nitin's answer still works out basically the same if you have $n^2$ instead of $\frac{1}{n^2}$. If you use the integral form of the remainder, you can even get a closed form for the sum...

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Using the LaGrangian error term,
$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} + \frac{e^{c_n}\;x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},$$
for some $c_n \in (0,x)$ or $c_n \in (x,0)$. Noting that $e^c$ is bounded in the interval, the convergence is the same as the convergence of the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n^2(n+1)!},
\end{align*}
which converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by the ratio test.

Comment: The $c$ depends on $n$.

Comment: Ah, right. But $c$ is between 0 and $x$, so it doesn't matter right? I suppose I can edit the proof by saying the final series is less than $e^x$ times the series?

Comment: Make that $\max(1,e^x)$ and you'll be fine.

Comment: Made an even lazier answer.